Get equal above/belowskip regardless of float for lstlisting
When using the listings package, for some listings I do not want to use float, i.e., I want the listing "inline."  The minimal example below shows such a listing.  The first lstlisting does not use float and the spacing above/below it is correct, i.e., a blank line.
For longer listings, however, I do want to use float.  The second lstlisting does use float, but the spacing above/below it is incorrect — specifically, it's too big as if it were two blank lines.
(The length of the second listing is short since that's all that's necessary to illustrate the problem.)
I want the spacing above/below listings with float to be the same as those without. How can I get what I want?

FYI: I did try just making all listings float and then changed \aboveskip and \belowskip to 0pt.  That mostly worked, but then I discovered that if a lstlisting is inside an itemize list, it's not indented properly to be "under" the bullet item. Listings without float work fine inside itemize lists.
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[flushmargin, hang, perpage, symbol*]{footmisc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  language=C,
  abovecaptionskip=\baselineskip,
  aboveskip=\baselineskip,
  belowcaptionskip=0pt,
  belowskip=\baselineskip,
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  breaklines=true,
  captionpos=b,
  floatplacement=hbt!,
  keepspaces=true,
  keywordstyle=\lst@ifdisplaystyle\bfseries\fi\normalsize,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  tabsize=2,
  xleftmargin=.4in
}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Chapter}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{lstlisting}
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf( "This listing has the correct amount of space above/below it.\n" );
}
\end{lstlisting}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{lstlisting}[float]
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf( "This listing with float has too much space above/below it.\n" );
}
\end{lstlisting}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}


just a comment that floats in lists work as designed. As they are document level inserts that may be written elsewhere and float in to a page with a list, or written in a list and float out of it, then they go to some effort to normalise away all the local settings and initialise with the document default widths and fonts.

@DavidCarlisle OK. Although it's somewhat orthogonal to my problem, to me it would make more sense if a float containing h behaved as if the float were not even there unless it actually had to float to the top of the next page; i.e., if it can be placed "here" and fits on the page, do nothing any differently.

perhaps, but in practice the float has already been typeset before the decsion on float placement is made, and that can't be undone (or couldn't be undone with the memory available in 1985) but it's I think more consistent to treat all floats the same.

@DavidCarlisle I don't suppose you happen to know how to get equal spacing regardless per my question? I'm stuck.

It's occurred to me for a while that \intextsep-worth of vertical space was being inserted by the normal float package in addition to the aboveskip and belowskip of the lstlistings package.
Assuming that's true, then what I want is:

If I have a listing I just want "inline" (no float), then I want aboveskip and belowskip to be \baselineskip.
However, if I have listing I want to float, then I want aboveskip and belowskip to be 0pt and \intextsep alone would give me the separation I want.

One way to do this is to define:
\lstset{
  language=C,
  abovecaptionskip=\medskipamount,
  aboveskip=\baselineskip,
  belowcaptionskip=0pt,
  belowskip=\baselineskip,
  floatplacement=hbt!,
  % ...
}

that is, define the default to have no float and a non-zero aboveskip and belowskip.
Then separately define:
\lstdefinestyle{float}{
  aboveskip=0pt,
  belowskip=0pt,
  float
}

Then when I want an inline listing, just do:
\begin{lstlisting}
int main() {
  // ...
\end{lstlisting}

but when I want a float listing, do:
\begin{lstlisting}[style=float]  % instead of: [float]
  // ...
\end{lstlisting}

that will both float and set aboveskip and belowskip to 0pt.
Since I also have a numbers style, I need two versions of that:
\lstdefinestyle{float-numbers}{
  aboveskip=0pt,
  belowskip=0pt,
  float,
  numbers=left,
  numbersep=1em,
  stepnumber=1
}

\lstdefinestyle{numbers}{
  numbers=left,
  numbersep=1em,
  stepnumber=1
}

This all seems to work.
